# CSS element automatically closing when active / selected

Tags: html, css

I have a searchbar, which is initially hidden until the user "hovers" over the div "searchbar". The issue I had was if the user did not stay hovered over the searchbar, it would then close and be hidden again. I wanted to change this to :active, meaning the user has to click to show and hide ... however, when changing the CSS to :active, the searchbar opens and instantly closes on itself. Also if I press once and hold down the mouse, it stays open...

Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

https://codepen.io/richag_ff/pen/bGayzeP

```
<div class="searchbar">
                                    @Html.TextBox("SearchText", ViewBag.SearchText as String, new { @class = "search_input", placeholder = "Search by part or reference" })
                                        <a href="#" class="search_icon"><i class="fa fa-search search_icon_i"></i></a>
                                </div>
```

[image]

```
.searchbar{
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    }

.search_input{
color: #858585;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
background: none;
width: 0;
caret-color:transparent;
line-height: 40px;
transition: width 0.4s linear;
}

.searchbar:hover > .search_input{
padding: 0 10px;
width: 215px;
caret-color:#000;
transition: width 0.4s linear;
}

.searchbar:hover > .search_icon{
background: white;
color: #000;
}


.search_icon{
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
float: right;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
border-radius: 50%;
color:#858585;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: `:active` will only trigger when you click on the element or you have selected it i.e the element is currently in active state. That's why the search bar closes immediately after showing up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

OP also needs the input to stay in the "open" state after it has been clicked and returned back to the "closed" state when clicked again. There were changes to the markup:

1. Add a hidden checkbox
2. `.searchbar` is a `<label>`
3. `.search-icon` is a `<b>` because an interactive tag like `<a>` will usually result in unexpected behavior when it is in another interactive tag (like `<label>`).

The toggling feature is possible by leveraging the checkbox/radio button association with `<label>`:

**Figure I**

```
// checkbox is display: none
<input id='switch' type='checkbox'>
//        ⇳ id and for must match
<label for='switch' class='searchbar'>
  <input id='search' type='search'><b 
  ...
</label>
```

when a chk/rad input is associated to a `<label>` -- whenever one is clicked by the user, the other is also clicked remotely. In oder to enable an association, the chk/rad must have an id and the `<label>` must have a `[for]` attribute with the chk/rad id (see ***figure I***).

When the `<label>` is clicked so is the checkbox which in turn changes it's state to `:checked`. Once checked, it can change all tags that proceed it by the use of [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), [general sibling combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator), and [descendant combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator). Unfortunately,  it's not perfect -- because the `<label>` is not clickable where the `input#search` resides. Only the areas to the left and right of `#search` is clickable. I made some outlines to popup whenever the `<label>` is clicked to indicate to the user that it's in a "locked" state.

[`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) state only happens when the user keeps the mouse button down. Use [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) on the input. The user clicks the input once and it's in the full length state until the user clicks elsewhere. The `.search-icon` can be controlled as well be using the adjacent sibling combinator:

**Figure II**

```
#search:focus + .search-icon {...
/* If input is focused by user then if the next tag has class 
.search-icon, apply the styles on .search-icon */
```

```css
html {
  font: 2ch/1.25 'Segoe UI'
}

.searchbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 4px groove lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#search {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  width: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: none;
  caret-color: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  transition: width 0.4s linear;
}

.searchbar:hover #search,
#search:focus,
#switch:checked+.searchbar #search {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 12px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border: 3px inset rgba(129, 129, 129, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  caret-color: #000;
}

#switch:checked+.searchbar #search {
  outline: 3px navy solid;
}

#switch:checked+.searchbar {
  background: #ddd;
}

.search-icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: -5%;
  color: #858585;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchbar:hover .search-icon,
#search:focus+.search-icon,
#switch:checked+.searchbar .search-icon {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px groove grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: border 0.3s linear;
}

#switch:checked+.searchbar .search-icon {
  outline: 3px navy solid;
  color: navy;
}

.fa-lg {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 2.5px;
}

#switch {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input id='switch' type='checkbox'>
<label for='switch' class="searchbar">
  <input id='search' name='search' type='search'>
  <b class="search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></b>
</label>
```

Comment: I want the searchbar (input) to stay open if there is text within the searchbar

Comment: Ok, it's possible with CSS, but I'll need to update later I have go soon.

Comment: @richag Ok, it's ready.

Comment: Did you update snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:focus` for this. But to get focus to work on a div you need to add `tabindex="-1"` to the div.

Because focus only works for 1 element. You can't focus on the input. Therefor we have to add a jQuery solution to fix it.

See snippet below! ✌️

```js
$('#TmInM').on('focus', function () {
    $('#TmInM').addClass('focus');
    $('#search').focus();
}).on('blur', function (e) {
    $('#TmInM').removeClass('focus');
    $('#search').blur();
});
$('#search').on('focus', function () {
    $('#TmInM').addClass('focus');
    $('#search').focus();
}).on('blur', function (e) {
    $('#TmInM').removeClass('focus');
    $('#search').blur();
});
```

```css
#TmInM {
    width:40vw;
    height:3.4vh;
    background: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10vw;
    margin-top:0.9vh;
    color:#777;
    border:2px solid transparent;
    outline:none;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px #BBB;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px #BBB;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px #BBB;
}
#TmInM.focus {
    border:2px solid #00b646;
    outline:none;
}
#TmInM img {
    float: left;
    margin-top:0.4vh;
    margin-left:0.4vw;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
#TmInM input {
    width:30vw;
    height:1.8vh;
    padding:0.2vw;
    margin-top:0.2vh;
    margin-left:0.2vw;
    font-size:0.8vw;
  border:0;
}
#TmInM input::placeholder {
    color:#CCC;
    font-style:italic;
}
#TmInM input:focus {
    border:2px solid transparent;
    outline:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px #FFF;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px #FFF;
}
#TmInM input:focus::placeholder {
    color:#999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TmInM" tabindex="-1">
            <img src="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>images/search.png" alt="" /><input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="inputmain" placeholder="Send out a leprechaun to go search what u are looking for..." value="" />
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately , making the changes suggested, it does not solve the issue. Now, it does nothing when clicking or hovering

Comment: https://codepen.io/richag_ff/pen/bGayzeP

Comment: will try your updated comment, bare with

Comment: I have updated my post with search bar I made yesterday.

Comment: `$('.searchbar').on('focus', function () {
    $('.searchbar').addClass('focus');
    $('#SearchText').focus();
}).on('blur', function (e) {
    $('.searchbar').removeClass('focus');
    $('#SearchText').blur();
});
$('#SearchText').on('focus', function () {
    $('.searchbar').addClass('focus');
    $('#SearchText').focus();
}).on('blur', function (e) {
    $('.searchbar').removeClass('focus');
    $('#SearchText').blur();
});`

And change `:hover` in your CSS with `.focus`

Comment: I have added <Script></script> with the above, changed :hover to .searchbar.focus > .search_input{ and also set the tabindex... and it does nothing when focusing, I am using jquery version 3.6.0

Comment: Here you are, https://jsfiddle.net/8kv2g0pc/

Comment: I have made one: jsfiddle.net/5vuzgkba It uses jQuery 2.1.3